# Using Custom Http Header in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, http-headers

i try to consume a SOA Service. I generate a Service Reference from the wsdl and then I instantiate a client object with my binding configuration, it is a basicHttpBinding.

Then i implement a custom behavior and a message inspector and there I add my custom header properties like shown below...

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request.Properties.Add("CONTENT-TYPE", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        request.Properties.Add("PropertyOne", "One");
        request.Properties.Add("PropertyTwo", "Two");

        return null;
    }
```

Then, when I try to consume the service, I get always the Error message

> (502) Bad Gateway.

With fiddler I look at the raw http data send to the service, the custom properties aren't in the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a custom HTTP header to a message, you need to add them to the `HttpRequestMessageProperty` instance of the message property bag:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty prop;
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
    }
    else
    {
        prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, prop);
    }

    prop.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
    prop.Headers["PropertyOne"] = "One";
    prop.Headers["PropertyTwo"] = "Two";

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar too and had luck with WeboperationContext

WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted; WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");

and it worked like a charm

Comment: Wrapping the code will be preferred by many people. Making the code and hit Ctrl + K will do.